# BarcodeReader by Zxing.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to use the library [ZXing.Net](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) to decode barcode images.
I've installed the library in AspNetCore-Mvc project, but I don't understand how to create an object of type BarcodeReader()

Where I can found some examples or docs?

Comment: Did you google? for example the third hit: https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/how-to-read-and-create-barcode-images-using-c-and-zxing-net/

Comment: Yes, of course... In the last version of ZXing.Net (v0.16.6),  the only way to use BarCodeReader is an object of type BarcodeReader(Func<T, LuminanceSource> createLuminanceSource); and I don't find any example

Comment: If you use .Net core you should select one of the binding packages of zxing.net to different image libraries:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zxing.net.bindings
for examples this one:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility/
With a binding you can instantiate a reader by var reader = new ZXing.<YourBindingHere>.BarcodeReader();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the reply of Micheal, I have decided to use the library ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility (v0.16.7)

I instantiate a redear object in this way:

```
 var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            Options = new DecodingOptions
            {
                TryHarder = true
            }
        };
var result = barcodeReader.Decode(bitmap);
```

The result variable contains the right infos.

Thanks!